# chef calling resource from recipe in same cookbook

Tags: resources, chef-infra, recipe

If I have a cookbook with a recipe and a resource. How do I call this resource from my recipe. Both the recipe and resource are in same cookbook. Do I still need to use cookbookname_resourcename? Do I also need to include the cookbook name in the metadata.rb?

Comment: Show your code if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use the full name even in the same cookbook but nothing fancy in the metadata.

Comment: I try using that and run kitchen converge but it give me below error-
================================================================================
       Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test/recipes/default.rb
       ================================================================================
       
       NoMethodError
       -------------
       No resource or method named `cookbookname' for `Chef::Recipe "default"'

Comment: Are you sure you did `cook_res` and not `cook res`?

Comment: yes I did a cook_res.  I am wondering if this works if we are testing our local cookbook   using kitchen converge

Comment: The error I got was-
 ****************************************
I try using that and run kitchen converge but it give me below error-  Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test/recipes/default.rb ========================================================= NoMethodError ------------- No resource or method named cookbookname_resource' for Chef::Recipe "default"' –
 ****************************************
There was typo while pasting the error last time as I modified the error output for security reasons

Comment: Can you please let me know which name u r talking about? I have the correct cookbook_res name in my recipe while calling the resource